# Apps don't show up in camera and microphone privacy settings in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, discord

I am using windows 11 and I am trying to get discord to accept inputs from my mic but it is detecting no input while in the windows sound settings page, there is input being recognised, I suspect this is a issue in the privacy settings, however, discord the app itself is not listed there.[image]

Comment: Start by allowing Desktop applications to access your microphone, Discord, is a Desktop application not a UWP application

Comment: @Ramhound, Brief as the comment is, should it not be an *answer*? It should resolve the issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - If it did solve the problem I’ll submit an answer.